# Capturing event for autocomplete textbox cross icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete box(**value 1**) on one of the page and textbox (**value 2**) just below it which gets populated on the selection of the searched term in autocomplete box.

[image]

When I click on the cross **(X)** appearing on the autocomplete box the **value 1** box gets cleared. My requirements are that I want to clear **value 2** box as well on click of cross button.

Is that even possible? I searched a lot on the internet but cannot find any answer to it.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Since I am new to UI technology, My normal approach is to select a particular element by using IE's DOM Explorer option and then attaching an event to it or any action according to my requirement. But the point I want to ask, is it even possible to attach an event to cross button ? if not what can be the solution

Comment: yes it is possible you can clear the value of value2 by clicking on cross button of value1

Comment: @TechLife Please share the code.

Comment: @TechLife Try below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need search event. Search event will trigger when user clicks on cross button.

1. onkeyup event will be triggered when user enters value in textbox.
2. onsearch event will be triggered when user clicks on cross button.

```js
function fillValue(e){
  //console.log(e.target.value);
  var txtAutoFill = document.getElementById("txt_auto_fill");
  txtAutoFill.value = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<label>Enter value </label><input type = "search" id="txt_auto" onsearch="fillValue(event)" onkeyup="fillValue(event)"/>
<br/>
<label>Will be auto filled</label>
<input type = "text" id="txt_auto_fill" />
```

Comment: [jsfiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/y8ko9q7u/) I have executed the code but I am getting error as "fillValue" is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lalit but the text from the 2nd box does not clear up on clicking cross on 1st box.

Comment: @TechLife you will have to change to load type in jsfiddle from onload to in head. You will have to click on javascript from there you can get option to edit load type. See updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y8ko9q7u/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lalit, the fiddle you provided worked :)